# django request getlist method: does this preserve the sequence of my posted parameters?

Tags: python, django, parameters

I am posting a sequence of image files and the corresponding description for each image. So the skeleton html form part:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="file" name="description">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="file" name="description">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="file" name="description">
</div>
```

My server is Django 1.6.11 and I want to use django's `getlist` for `image` param and `description` param. So I want to make sure that the two lists I got--`image_list` and `description_list` do match, meaning that `image_list[0]` indeed matches with `description_list[0]`, `image_list[1]` indeed matches with `description_list[1]` and `image_list[2]` indeed matches with `description_list[2]`.

Based on what I see when tests with Chrome and Django 1.6.11, it seems that the corresponding relationship is guaranteed. However, I am not sure if this applies all the time.

Comment: The QuerySet class mimics the dictionary object in many ways but can handle having multiple keys of the same value.There isn't a way to enforce ordering on it, however it is reasonable to assume the when you are POSTing that the inputs are read in linear fashion and serialized in linear fashion. BUT this is not something you should do in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should rely on the sequence of `getlist`. Instead you should give different names to each `<input>`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="image0">
    <input type="file" name="description0">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="image1">
    <input type="file" name="description1">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="image2">
    <input type="file" name="description2">
</div>
```

Then in your views you could do:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    file = request.POST['image%s' % i]
    description = request.POST['description%s' % i]
    # other operations
```